# Creating a Sharepoint link to an live excel workbook and have it update automatically

Tags: excel, document

I need to create a link on a sharepoint page which when selected, opens an excel file. Only problem is the excel file will be updated daily from within the drive location it is stored in.

I do not want the users to be able to edit the excel file, just view it daily.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

First put that Excel file in one of the SharePoint library and then provide the link of the file in the SharePoint Page. Going forward you can always come and edit the excel file stored in SharePoint library and update it there itself.

The links wont change . And you can always give only read permission to the excel file in the library to the end users. You dont have to modify it everyday